# Is there a way to create a nested data table in React?

Tags: json, reactjs

I have tried to create a table like this:
[table that I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oKbao.png)

But when I followed this tutorial https://codesandbox.io/s/material-ui-table-demo-with-row-span-dq1w6?file=/demo.js and try it in many way, the result just not correct.

This is my result: https://codesandbox.io/s/material-ui-table-demo-with-row-span-1hhvv?file=/demo.js

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution needs to be tidied but the concept is there.

The trick here is to have the first column with a `rowspan` equal to the last columns row count. To do this you must accumulate the length of all `details` within each `datas`.

Here is a working example:

```
export default function SpanningTable() {
  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <Paper className={classes.root}>
      <Table className={classes.table}>
        <TableHead>
          <TableRow>
            <TableCell>ROOT</TableCell>
            <TableCell>DATA</TableCell>
            <TableCell>DETAIL</TableCell>
          </TableRow>
        </TableHead>
        <TableBody>
          {sample.map(root => (
            <Fragment>
              <TableRow>
                <TableCell rowSpan={root.datas.reduce((length, data) => length + data.details.length + 1, 0) + 1}>
                  {root.name}
                </TableCell>
              </TableRow>
              {root.datas.map(data => (
                <Fragment>
                  <TableRow  >
                    <TableCell rowSpan={data.details.length + 1}>{data.name}</TableCell>
                  </TableRow>
                  {data.details.map(detail => (
                      <TableRow>
                        <TableCell>{detail.name}</TableCell>
                      </TableRow>
                  ))}
                </Fragment>
              ))}
            </Fragment>
          ))}
        </TableBody>
      </Table>
    </Paper>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thank your for your answer. You save my days